# Printing the number from a list and its square on the same line in python3

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, line

So what I want is basically from a list of numbers (`numbers=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]`) to print the number and its square on the same line. The output it should be something like:

```
1 1
2 4
3 9
4 16
5 25
6 36
...
or
...
1, 1
2, 4
3, 9
...
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because you didn't do anything by yourself and waiting that somebody else will write code for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
for i in numbersList:
    print(i, i*i)
```

Comment: So simple... I am a begginer. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1):

one line answer:

```
print('\n'.join(['{0} {1}'.format(number, number**2) for number in numbers]))
```

Comment: Wont work like that...

Comment: @xXliolauXx..why did you say that?

Comment: @Iron Fist im sorry to have misread something there. Please take my upvote as an excuse ;)

Comment: @IronFist thanks, I take the upvote ;)